# Apache2 error logs to slack channel web hook

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-4, slack-api

I have numerous error logs sending to slack channel. To count a few
I have application exceptions sending to my slack channel, ping my web server for error status, send admin message when customers make orders and so on.

Slack is very useful for real time alert. I am using monit for monitoring my services but monit can only send to a criteria to email.

Today I got an application error because I don't have enough memory on my amazon ec2 instance. It took me a couple of minutes to realize that my web server was down.

I am looking on how to set up apache2 web server error log with slack web hook. Existing solution is welcome but I am also open for a bit of hacking on apache2 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution. It does not send apache log to slack but I can have apache log to a cloud server that is more powerful to query and make an alert.

[Loggy https://www.loggly.com/](https://www.loggly.com/) and [Papertrail https://papertrailapp.com/](https://papertrailapp.com/)

They are very powerful. I myself now use Papertrail. Papertrail is easy to install. It uses remote system log that can capture any log file, tagging and send to it cloud server. we can perform search in the cloud very easily.